# Play 2.4 HTTP Cache (Cached) invalidate for non idempotent requests (EhCache)

Tags: caching, playframework, ehcache, playframework-2.4

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/ScalaCache

I read that but it doesn't say how to invalidate `Cached` object (HTTP Cache) for non idempotent requests. If we do POST / PUT / DELETE, how can we invalidate it ? With injection, and cached object, I cannot access `CacheApi` object (which holds remove methods).

And another question, how to deal with async actions in controllers ?

Thanks

EDIT: sample code.
FindById cache the response. I want to keep it until a non idempotent request arrive, like POST and then invalidate cache in insert controller method

```
@Inject() (val pushService: PushDbService, val cached: Cached)


def findById(id: String) = {
    val caching = cached
      .status(_ => "/pushes/findById"+ id, 200)
      .includeStatus(404, 60)

    caching {
      Action.async{
        pushService.findById(id).map{
          case Some(partner) => Ok(Json.toJson(partner))
          case None => NotFound
        }
      }
    }
  }


def insert() = Action.async(parse.json){ req =>
    req.body.validate[Push] match{
      case validatedPush: JsSuccess[Push] =>
        ***INVALIDATE CACHE HERE***
        pushService.insert(validatedPush.get).map{
          case Some(id) => Created(Json.toJson(id))
          case None => InternalServerError("Cannot insert object.")
        }
      case JsError(wrongPush) =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Body cannot be validated: "+wrongPush))
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I cannot access CacheApi'?

Comment: Cached has got an injected class param, of type CacheApi. But I cannot use it I don't know why ... Maybe I'm missing something simple

Comment: Would you give a sample code, please?

Comment: Post Edited, with 2 methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cached` is just a [helper](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.Cached) to add caching to Action. It does not contain any `remove` methods. If you want to alter the cache, inject `CacheApi` to your controller.

```
@Inject()(val pushService: PushDbService, val cached: Cached, val cache: CacheApi)
```

And invalidate the cache:

```
cache.remove("/pushes/findById" + id)
```

Keep in mind, your actions are asynchronous. It would make sense to set/remove cache entry as soon as `Future` is redeemed.

Answer (score 0):

Mon Calamari response is valid. My code snippet:

```
def insert() = Action.async(parse.json){ req =>
    req.body.validate[Push] match{
      case validatedPush: JsSuccess[Push] =>
        pushService.insert(validatedPush.get).map{
          case Some(id) =>
            cache.remove(cacheKey)
            Created(Json.toJson(id))
          case None =>
            InternalServerError("Cannot insert object.")
        }
      case JsError(wrongPush) =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Body cannot be validated: "+wrongPush))
    }
  }

def findById(id: String) = Action.async{
    cache.get[Option[Push]](cacheKey+id) match{
      case Some(Some(value)) =>
        Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(value)))
      case Some(None) =>
        Future.successful(NotFound)
      case None =>
        pushService.findById(id).map{
          case Some(partner) =>
            cache.set(cacheKey+id,Some(partner))
            Ok(Json.toJson(partner))
          case None =>
            cache.set(cacheKey+id,None)
            NotFound
        }
    }
  }
```

Thanks a lot !!